# MySQL delete results 30 days and older using Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to delete all records that are older than 30 days.

This is what i have tried.

```
 $remove = DB::table('applicants')
              ->whereRaw('AppDate < date_sub(now() - 30 day)')
              ->delete();
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the above code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'day)' at line 1

Comment: You don't have to use DATE_SUB.. MySQL supports substracting dates with minus interval like so `WHERE AppDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`...

Comment: The good news is that it looks like you have a MySQL syntax problem, rather than something to do with Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp) function:

```
->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(NOW(), AppDate) > 30')
```

Comment: That will cause MySQL to not use a index (if anny on AppDate)

Comment: You're right. You should post your answer from the comment above as an answer because it's a better option if there's an index on AppDate.